# makedirs error: can GAE Python create new directories (folders) or not?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, file-io, directory

I have seen a number of questions relating to writing files & creating new directories using Python and GAE, but a number of them conclude (not only on SO) by saying that Python **cannot** write files or create new directories. Yet these commands exist and plenty of other people seem to be writing files and opening directories no problem.

I'm trying to write to .txt files and create folders and getting the following errors:

Case #1:

```
with open("aardvark.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("i can't believe its not butter")
```

produces "IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'aardvark.txt'".  But i've checked and it's def-o not a read only file.

Case #2:

```
folder = r'C:\project\folder\' + str(name)
os.makedirs(folder)
```

produces "OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: 'C:\project\folder'"

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appengine does not support any write operations to the filesystem (amongst other restrictions).
The BlobStore does have a file like api, but you cannot rewrite/append to existing blob store entities.  The dev server also presents these restrictions to emulate production environment.

You should probably have a read of the some of the docs about appengine.
The overview doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview explicitly states you can't write.

Comment: OK thanks Tim that is crystal clear - i'll read that link for sure. The followup HAS to be then... what are `os.makedirs` and `file write` functions FOR then?

Comment: THe general python methods for doing exactly what they say. However the runtime/sandbox is for a number of reasons not exactly the same as running on a normal server. Not being able to write to the local filesystem from running code is a good security measure.

Comment: Any suggestions of other than GAE where to go for free hosting and file writing ability???

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine can now write to a local "ephemeral" disk storage when using Managed-VM which is not supported when using the sandbox method as specified on this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/tutorial/step3