# How to make google app engine to support django's ImageField?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Currently I'm working on a django app which runs on the top of google app engine. One of a field of model looks like,

```
picture = models.ImageField()
```

But it shows the below error while saving that particular model

```
  File "/django_projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 93, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/django_projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/core/files/storage.py", line 63, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/django_projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/core/files/storage.py", line 248, in _save
    fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)
  File "/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 73, in fake_open
    raise OSError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: u'/django_projects/backend/src/Screenshot_from_2014-04-18_190527.png'
```

After some researches I found that, [GAE won't support writing operations to file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699948/3297613) . Think I need to use GAE's `blobstore` or Google Cloud storage. But I don't know how to integrate these with the django's model.

Answer (score 5):

To be specific, Django doesn't support App Engine's Cloud Storage or Datastore by default and requires custom storage providers to work with them. These are the solutions which are covered by the official Google docs:

- [Django non-rel](http://django-nonrel.org/) which supports App Engine Datastore. See also the related [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel?hl=en) in the Cloud Platform documentation.
- If you prefer to use CloudSQL or an external MySQL database as a back-end, you can use the django.db.backends.mysql module as per [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django).

There are also the following unofficial projects:

- [Djangae](https://djangae.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is a newer project geared specifically towards App Engine Datastore.
- The '[django-appengine-toolkit](https://github.com/masci/django-appengine-toolkit)' supports Cloud Storage.

If you want to implement your own storage provider using Cloud Storage you can take a look at [storage.py](https://github.com/masci/django-appengine-toolkit/blob/master/appengine_toolkit/storage.py) from django-appengine-toolkit as a reference.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you don't want to use any external solutions you'll need to write your own storage provider for Django. You can still use the source from any of these projects as a reference.